# Cumulated sums in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I have a problem, I need to do an acomulative sum for each month of each year and I have been searching the internet and the solution is to use the ORDER (ORDER BY), but it gives me an error that there is an error near order and it does not explain me nothing more. The syntax is correct according to the internet, but I do not understand why it does not go. I tried to convert the date to string but it does not let me either. Any solution for this?

This is my consult:

```
SELECT YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT) AÑO,
       MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT) MES, 
       COD_MAQUINA ,
       SUM(CANTIDAD_OK) SUMA,
       SUM(CANTIDAD_OK) OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(mm,FECHA_IMPUT)) AS suma        
FROM RTMAQUINA
WHERE COD_MAQUINA='LB_TRASVASE'
GROUP BY COD_MAQUINA, MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT),YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT)
ORDER BY YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT), MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT) ASC
```

ERROR: incorrect syntax near the order

[Result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj0L7.png)

[ERROR: incorrect syntax near the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve0Bi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you want is:

```
SELECT YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT) AÑO,
       MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT) MES, 
       COD_MAQUINA ,
       SUM(CANTIDAD_OK) SUMA,
       SUM(SUM(CANTIDAD_OK)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT) ORDER BY MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT)) AS suma        
FROM RTMAQUINA
WHERE COD_MAQUINA = 'LB_TRASVASE'
GROUP BY COD_MAQUINA, 
         MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT),
         YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT)
ORDER BY YEAR(FECHA_IMPUT), MONTH(FECHA_IMPUT) ASC;
```

Note the nested `SUM()`s.  This syntax looks awkward, but is correct when using window functions with aggregation functions.  The inner `SUM()` is the aggregation.  The outer `SUM()` is for the window function.

Also note the window clause.  First, it needs to reference the same expressions used in the `GROUP BY` -- or aggregation functions.  Second, I think you want to partition by year based on how your question is phrased.

Comment: ORDER BY won't work in that case and will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @PedroBonifácio . . . SQL Server has supported cumulative sums using `ORDER BY` since version 2012.  Previous versions are at the end of their lifecycle, so this code should work.

Comment: I was wrong. SQL Server accepts functions in clause ORDER BY.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried your solution and still give me the same error

Comment: @RJ . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?  What is your compatibility level?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The version of sql server is this:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (Intel X86) 
Sep 16 2010 20:09:22 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM)